# Laravel authorization via email, password and additional field

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, authorization

Out of the box Laravel authorizes users by matching email (default - can be overridden) and password.

Is it possible to authorize user using 3 fields, e.g:

1. email
2. password
3. group

... where 'group' is some additional field from 'users' database.

In other words, user can belong to group:1 and can login to group:1 resources only, but not to group:2 using his group:1 credentials.

If user belongs to group:1 and group:2, then he needs different credentials to login to either group.

Additionally, user can use same email for both groups. In such case it is group number that would act as additional identifier. And of course passwords would be different.

I am thinking setting a database multiple column index on fields 'id' and 'group' would be a good start, but I fail to grasp (yet), what would be required to make Laravel authorization process sensitive to 3 fields, instead of 2.

I would appreciate some pointers.

Comment: what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: While we of course do not know the specifics of your application, to me it does not sound very user friendly to require different credentials for the same website. Is it an options to use the default auth but let the user switch groups in the application?

Comment: I use Laravel 5.4

Comment: @milo526 as always, it is all down to project and choices client makes to get his expected outcome

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you're trying to achieve a form of tenancy on data belonging to certain groups only. Have a look at this package:

https://github.com/HipsterJazzbo/Landlord

In essence, you would add a `group_id` field to the tables where you wish to restrict access and then using middleware, apply an additional `where('group_id', Auth::user()->group_id)` clause to any database queries. This works very well for retrieving subsets of data belonging to specific users by their role, for example.